# javascript or css - almost working, running into some snags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

below I'll provide the code I currently have - html, css and javascript.  Everything is working properly except 1 minor thing, and I can't seem to figure it out.  I am still fairly new to javascript and think that javascript is needed to make this work, if not - it's got to be in my css...

If you click on each div with the titles (NoS Members), (Registered Members), and (Team Profiles) you will see that the slider background image (small triangle) works and is active upon clicking any one of the three divs - which in doing so opens up another container below it.  That all works perfectly, however, the issue I'm running into is that if you click on the (NoS Members) one first, then go in order to the right and click on either the 2nd one - (Registered Members), or the last one (Team Profiles), then try clicking back on the 2nd - (Registered Members) or 1st one - (NoS Members), the slider doesn't work going back sliding to the left.  It only appears to work sliding to the right once a click has taken place.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/5DTKH/

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="profile_selection">
    <a href="#nos_profiles" class="profile_selection">{ÑØ§}<br />Members</a>
    <a href="#registered_profiles" class="profile_selection">Registered<br />Members</a>
    <a href="#team_profiles" class="profile_selection">Team<br />Profiles</a>
    <div id="profile_selection_slider"></div>
</div>
<div id="nos_profiles" class="selection">
</div>
<div id="registered_profiles" class="selection">
</div>
<div id="team_profiles" class="selection">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#profile_selection { width: 612px; height: 152px; padding: 0; margin: 15px auto; position: relative; }
#profile_selection a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 105px;
  padding: 45px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  border: 2px solid #444;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000, 0 28px 24px -24px #000;
  float: left;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
  color: #FFF;
  font: 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
#profile_selection a:hover, #profile_selection a.active {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  background: #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  color: #DF7401;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Profile - Selection - Slider' ===== */
#profile_selection_slider {
  width: 64px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(http://www.nosclan.net/images/Home/menu_bg_hover.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 152px;
  left: 275px;
  z-index: 4;
}
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1).active ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 71px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 275px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 480px; }
/* ===== Start of 'NoS - Profiles' ===== */
#nos_profiles {
  width: 950px;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Registered - Profiles' ===== */
#registered_profiles {
  width: 950px;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* ===== Start of 'Team - Profiles' ===== */
#team_profiles {
  width: 950px;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #222;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0.3em 0.9em 0.3em #000;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.profile_selection').click( function(){
       var a = $(this);
       $('a.profile_selection').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       var selection = $( a.attr('href'));
       selection.removeClass('selection');
       $('.selection').hide();
       selection.addClass('selection');
       if( selection.is(':visible')){
           selection.slideToggle(400)
       }else{selection.slideToggle(400)
        };
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated - not sure if this matters either, but I am using the jquery library 1.3.2 -- I know it's outdated, but it is what it is...

Lastly, I do want to re-thank Ashis and Nick for helping me with a different question of which is relevant to this.

Comment: Working fine for me in Chrome 27.0.1453.116

Comment: does the background image slide back to the left after clicking the 3rd div titled (Team Profiles)?  It's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your css lines 53 to 55 from this

```
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1).active ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 71px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 275px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider, #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 480px; }
```

to this

```
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1).active ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 71px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 275px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3).active ~ #profile_selection_slider { left: 480px; }

#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 71px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 275px; }
#profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ #profile_selection_slider{ left: 480px; }
```

so the :hover can work even if other #profile_selection is .active
http://jsfiddle.net/5DTKH/2/

Comment: Interesting, let me give this a try and I'll get back to you.  Isn't what you put the exact same as what I already had though?  The only difference is that I separated mine with a comma and you have yours on different lines?  Why is it with your way it works, but the way I originally had it doesn't?  Very curious?

Comment: Tested and works like a charm - Thank you for your help.  Why is it though that I had to put those on separate lines in the css?  I thought the comma signifies that both id's are the same?

Comment: its the same but the css rules order is also important the way you have it the rules of #profile_selection a:nth-of-type(3) will be allways used if it is .active as the other rules a:nth-of-type(1) and a:nth-of-type(2) affect the same element #profile_selection_slider so the way to fix it is put all the .active rules first so the :hover rule is used even if another element is .active

Comment: Ohhhh, talk about a brain fart...lol.  Thank you for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 2):

I have made few changes in above code and updated the fiddle [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DTKH/4/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var clicked;
$('a.profile_selection').click( function(){
   var a = $(this);
    clicked=$(this);
 $('a.profile_selection').not(clicked).removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var selection = $( a.attr('href'));
   selection.removeClass('selection');
   $('.selection').hide();
   selection.addClass('selection');
   if( selection.is(':visible')){
       selection.slideToggle(400)
   }else{selection.slideToggle(400)
    };
});
$('a.profile_selection').hover(function(){
var a = $(this);
   $('a.profile_selection').not(clicked).removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
  })
});
```

Comment: This is very close - I'd like the hover to stay put (in place) once div is clicked, but still have the ability to hover over the other 2 options with the slider moving with it until another div is clicked...Does that make sense at all?

Comment: I gave you a plus one for helping, but my issue was solved simply because of a few css lines were misplaced - Thank you for helping out though.